# Concatenate strings in JSF/JSP EL and Javascript

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces, el

I'm having troubles with EL and javascript functions (JSF 1.2, Facelets, Richfaces 3.3.0GA). I have a page that includes another composition:

```
<ui:include src="/pages/panels/examinationPanel.xhtml">
<ui:param name="prefix" value="new" />
```

And in my `ui:composition` I want to append the `prefix` to every id. For example:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="#{prefix}_examinationPanel">
```

That works ok.

But the problem comes when I want to access the components in functions suchs as `oncomplete` I cannot get it to concatenate the strings properly. For example

```
oncomplete="#{rich:component('#{prefix}_examinationPanel')}.show();"
```

I've tried with `fn:join` as well but it does not execute the function because it complains about errors when it finds "#" character. For example:

```
 oncomplete="#{rich:component(fn:join(#{prefix},'examinationPanel'))}.show()"
```

throws

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "fn:join( #" at line 1, column 33.

Encountered "fn:join( #"
```

Different errors if I brace it with brackets or with # and brackets.

What am I doing wrong?

And another question, in a conditional command like

```
oncomplete="#{a}?#{b}:#{c}"
```

How can I "group" to be able to execute more actions when true or false? Por example something like this:

```
oncomplete="#{a}?(#{b}#{f}):(#{c}#{d}#{e})"
```

I've tried with parenthesis but does not parse it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using facelets. I edited the post to add that info, which indeed is relevant

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you are using Facelets, here's a relatively good solution:

- create `functions.taglib.xml` in your WEB-INF
- add a context param indicating the location:

  ```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
      <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/functions.taglib.xml
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```
- In the xml put the following:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
    "https://facelets.dev.java.net/source/browse/*checkout*/facelets/src/etc/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
  <facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSF/Facelet">
      <namespace>http://yournamespace.com/fnc</namespace>
      <function>
          <function-name>concat</function-name>
          <function-class>com.yourpackage.utils.Functions</function-class>
          <function-signature>
              java.lang.String concat(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
          </function-signature>
      </function>
  </facelet-taglib>
  ```
- in the page use the following:

  ```
  xmlns:fnc="http://yournamespace.com/fnc"
  ....
  oncomplete="#{rich:component(fnc:concat(prefix, '_examinationPanel'))}.show();"
  ```
- finally, in the `Function` class define the simple method:

  ```
  public static String concat(String string1, String string2) {
     return string1.concat(string2);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to try it right now.

One question, the trailing ";" for the param-value is intentional?

And the other, isn't this the same as "fn:join" (which does not work)

Comment: hm, no. I copied it from my configs, so it doesn't seem to do any harm either.

Comment: I've tried it and it works. And besides, I've learn a lesson about creating your own namespaces and functions :). Thanks for the fast and complete answer.

Answer (score 15):

a simpler solution is to manage the String in the EL like an Object and use the method concat from the class String, something like this:

```
#{rich:component('constantString'.concat(variable))}.show();
```

Comment: Note that this only works in EL 2.2 or JBoss EL (for EL 2.1). OP didn't indicate that he's using Servlet 3.0 nor JBoss Seam.

Comment: In that case he should consider adding EL 2.2 support, especially for the ability to pass parameters in function calls.