# Rich Tooltip for SelectItem

Tags: jsf, richfaces

How to attach a `rich:tooltip` to the list generated by `f:selectItems` when using a variable for the attribute `for` inside the `rich:tooltip`.

This code works fine (the value of `#{prefix}` is `theprefixvalue`

```
<ui:composition>
<a4j:form id="#{prefix}_form">
<h:selectOneRadio style="text-align:left" id="#{prefix}_rating">
<f:selectItems value="#{test.options}"></f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneRadio>&nbsp; 
<rich:toolTip for="theprefixvalue_form\:theprefixvalue_rating\:0">a</rich:toolTip>      
</a4j:form>
</ui:composition>
```

But this code does not:

```
<ui:composition>
<h:outputText value="#{prefix}" />
<a4j:form id="#{prefix}_form">
<h:selectOneRadio style="text-align:left" id="#{prefix}_rating">
<f:selectItems value="#{test.options}"></f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneRadio>&nbsp; 
<rich:toolTip for="#{prefix}_form\:#{prefix}_rating\:0">a</rich:toolTip>        
</a4j:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: theprefixvalue_rating
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:612)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findComponentFor(RendererUtils.java:1037)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolTipRenderer.getTargetId(ToolTipRenderer.java:234)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ToolTipRenderer.constructJSVariable(ToolTipRenderer.java:251)
...
```

TestBean is session scoped and this is the code for getOptions();

```
public List<SelectItem> getOptions(){
    List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    options.add(new SelectItem("a","a"));
    options.add(new SelectItem("b","b"));
    options.add(new SelectItem("c","c"));
    return options;

}
```

Any ideas? The goal is to have a tooltip when the mouse is over the different options. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Apparently `HtmlSelectOneRadio` is not implementing `NamingContainer`, so it fails at `UIComponentBase` line 611:
(`result` is an instance of `HtmlSelectOneRadio`, `length>0` and `segments[1] = "theprefixvalue_rating"`)

```
        if (result != null && (!(result instanceof NamingContainer)) && length > 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(segments[i]);
```

I am trying to use my own `NamedHtmlSelectOneRadio` which extends `HtmlSelectOneRadio` and implements `NamingContainer` but I'm still guessing how to inject it with facelets. Any idea?

Comment: I enabled it by mistake, and I don't know how to disable it (can't from edit).

Comment: Once a post is made Community Wiki it's considered owned by the community, so that flag can't be undone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it.

I created my own component called `NamedHtmlSelectOneRadio` which is just a wrapper of `HtmlSelectOneRadio` but implements `NamingContainer`. I don't know if this will have further implications through the rest of JSF code, but my testcase works fine. Anyway, I'll update this answer if I find any strange behavior, as well as I'll post in the Mojarra implementation of JSF regarding why `HtmlSelectOneRadi`o does not implements `NamingContainer` out-of-the-box.

Here are the steps to create your own component with facelets.

1 Wrap the class:

import javax.faces.component.NamingContainer;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneRadio;

```
public class NamedHtmlSelectOneRadio extends HtmlSelectOneRadio implements NamingContainer {

    public NamedHtmlSelectOneRadio(){
        super();
    }

}
```

2 Wrap the Tag class and set the above class as component Type:

```
import com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectOneRadioTag;

public class NamedHtmlSelectOneRadioTag extends SelectOneRadioTag {

    public NamedHtmlSelectOneRadioTag(){
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public String getComponentType() {
        return "javax.faces.NamedHtmlSelectOneRadio";
    }

}
```

3 Add the component to your `faces-config.xml` configuration:

```
<component>
<component-type> com.eyeprevent.util.NamedHtmlSelectOneRadio </component-type>
<component-class> com.eyeprevent.util.NamedHtmlSelectOneRadio </component-class>
</component>
```

4 Add the tag to your taglib (mine is functions.taglib.xml). More info about creating your own taglib [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192759/concatenate-strings-in-jsf-jsp-el-and-javascript)

```
<tag>
<tag-name>namedSelectOneRadio</tag-name>
<component>
<component-type>com.eyeprevent.util.NamedHtmlSelectOneRadio</component-type>
</component>
</tag>`
```

5 Include the new taglib in your .xhtml (or .jsf) page and replace the `h:selectOneRadio` with your own (mine is `fnc:namedSelectOneRadio`)

```
xmlns:fnc="http://eyeprevent.com/fnc"
...

<fnc:namedSelectOneRadio id="#{prefix}_rating">
<f:selectItems value="#{test.options}"></f:selectItems>
</fnc:namedSelectOneRadio>
<rich:toolTip for="#{prefix}_form\:#{prefix}_rating:0">a</rich:toolTip>
```

And that's all!