# Cant access to java.util.HashMap$Entry with modifiers "public final"

Tags: java, glassfish, hashmap

My problem is, that my app works fine run locally on Tomcat server, but throws errors on server with installed glassfish.
Whole problem is that i'm iterate looking through HashMap in JSTL.
Server throws an stack as below:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.HashMap$Entry with modifiers "public final" 
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95) 
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261) 
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
```

problem is caused by code:

```
<c:forEach items="${element.getPreparedParameters()}" var="parametr" varStatus="j">
    documents["${i.index}"]["param"]=new Array();
    documents["${i.index}"]["param"]["key"] = "${parametr.getKey()}";
    documents["${i.index}"]["param"]["value"] = "${parametr.getValue()}";
</c:forEach>
```

Where `element.getPreparedParameters()` returns `HashMap`.

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out [this decades-old bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4207233) reported to Sun against Java 1.2 (fixed in [Java 11](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8046171)). I remember seeing this error before and the message is misleading: the problem lies not with the method modifiers, but with the modifiers on the owning class. Namely, `Map.Entry` is a public interface, but the implementing class in `HashMap` is private. Reflection doesn't allow you to access the methods of the class even though you are accessing methods that implement a public interface.

I'd suggest going for a cheap workaround: don't iterate over the `entrySet`, but over the `keySet` and use `map.get(key)` instead of `entry.getValue()`.

Alternative would be updating to Java 11 or newer.

Comment: im done with work for today, but i'll try it tommorrow morning. But question is, why does it work on Tomcat servers?

Comment: Problem solved. Iterate over keySet fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is very inefficient as the full map lookup happens again during every get(x).

Comment: @CharlesFollet "Very inefficient"---by what standard? Can you quantify the percentage it will add to the response time?

Comment: As you should know, O(n) in the worst case. I will do a workbench for response time soon.

Comment: @CharlesFollet As you should know, O(1) is the typical case, which is the point of a hashtable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Should have quoted  [Bauke Scholtz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10934104/3042945)

Comment: @CharlesFollet I don't see the point. Are you pulling an argument from authority? His advice quite obviously doesn't work, which is why this question arose in the first place.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik My knowlege ends here. My comment was just a warning I learnt from BalusC comment (that I can't share with a link). You can respond his comment if you want further informations, I would be happy to see his arguments.

Comment: @CharlesFollet I think I already have all the information I need, but thanks.