# How to iterate a map on XHTML pages?

Tags: jsf

I have a list like below

```
List<Map<String,List<ActivitiesData>>>
```

When I tried to iterate map in xhtml page I am able to get the `List<ActivitiesData>` values but I am unable to get the key(String) from map

The code is like below.

```
<ui:repeat var="timelineDateMapObject" value="#{timelineBean.timelineList}">
    <ui:repeat value="#{timelineDateMapObject.keySet().toArray()}" var="x">
        <ui:repeat var="timelineData" value="#{timelineDateMapObject.get(x)}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 20px;"> #{timelineData.hoursAndMiniuts}</td>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 20px;"> #{timelineData.type}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 20px;">
                    <h:graphicImage style="height: 50px; width: 50px" value="#{timelineData.url}" />
                </td>

                <td style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 20px;">#{timelineData.text}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td height="25px"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

Anyone please tell me how can I display key from map?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12699951/4074715

Comment: I tried like above link but i am unable to get the individual values i am getting like 07-01-2015 06-01-2015

Comment: I've added an answer so we can talk over concrete code, I'll delete it if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ui:repeat var="timelineDateMapObject" value="#{timelineBean.timelineList}">
    <c:forEach items="#{timelineDateMapObject}" var="timelineData">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 20px;"> #{timelineData.value.hoursAndMiniuts}</td>

                <td style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 20px;"> #{timelineData.value.type}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 20px;">
                    <h:graphicImage style="height: 50px; width: 50px" value="#{timelineData.value.url}" />
                </td>

                <td style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 20px;">#{timelineData.value.text}</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25px"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>    
</ui:repeat>
```