# HashMap in JSF not showing the value if the key is a non standard Object

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, hashmap, jsf-1.2

I have a HashMap which looks like this:

```
HashMap<QualifiedProduct,List<Date>
```

so my java code looks like this:

```
@Name("testController")
@AutoCreate
public class TestController {
public HashMap<QualifiedProduct, List<Date>> createAndReturnHashmap(){

    HashMap<QualifiedProduct, List<Date>> hm = new HashMap<QualifiedProduct, List<Date>>();

    QualifiedProduct q1= new QualifiedProduct();
    q1.setAbstractProductId(1);
    q1.setAbstractProductCode("1-1");
    q1.setAbstractProductName("one");
    q1.setAbstractProductTypeName("type1");
    q1.setCustomersCount(1);
    q1.setQualificationDueDate(new Date());
    q1.setQualificationsCount(1);

    QualifiedProduct q2= new QualifiedProduct();
    q2.setAbstractProductId(2);
    q2.setAbstractProductCode("2-2");
    q2.setAbstractProductName("two");
    q2.setAbstractProductTypeName("type2");
    q2.setCustomersCount(2);
    q2.setQualificationDueDate(new Date());
    q2.setQualificationsCount(2);

    QualifiedProduct q3= new QualifiedProduct();
    q3.setAbstractProductId(3);
    q3.setAbstractProductCode("3-3");
    q3.setAbstractProductName("three");
    q3.setAbstractProductTypeName("type3");
    q3.setCustomersCount(3);
    q3.setQualificationDueDate(new Date());
    q3.setQualificationsCount(3);



    List<Date> dt = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Date d1 = new Date();
    Date d2 = new Date();
    Date d3 = new Date();
    dt.add(d1);
    dt.add(d2);
    dt.add(d3);
    hm.put(q1, dt);
    hm.put(q2, dt);
    hm.put(q3, dt);

    return hm;

}
```

as i read in many other postings on stackoverflow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp),or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697519/jsf-1-2-iterate-over-a-map-that-contains-collections)  the best way to show it in JSF 1.2 is using the good old jsp tag `<c:forEach`

So i used in my code:

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
.....
<c:forEach var="hm" items="${testController.createAndReturnHashmap()}">
  ${hm.key} <br/>
  and value is:  ${hm.value} <br/><br/>
</c:forEach>
```

The JSF output is:

> com.dw.model.QualifiedProduct@15d97b65[abstractProductId=2,abstractProductCode=2-2,abstractProductName=two,abstractProductTypeName=type2,qualificationsCount=2,customersCount=2,qualificationDueDate=Thu Jun 11 14:47:37 CEST
>   2015,id=,version=,created=,modified=] and
>   value is:
>
> com.dw.model.QualifiedProduct@2393366a[abstractProductId=1,abstractProductCode=1-1,abstractProductName=one,abstractProductTypeName=type1,qualificationsCount=1,customersCount=1,qualificationDueDate=Thu Jun 11 14:47:37 CEST
>   2015,id=,version=,created=,modified=] and
>   value is:
>
> com.dw.model.QualifiedProduct@79342f17[abstractProductId=3,abstractProductCode=3-3,abstractProductName=three,abstractProductTypeName=type3,qualificationsCount=3,customersCount=3,qualificationDueDate=Thu Jun 11 14:47:37 CEST
>   2015,id=,version=,created=,modified=] and
>   value is:

So the value is always empty.

but if i use a HashMap like this `HashMap<String,List<Date>>` everything works:

```
public HashMap<String, List<Date>> createAndReturnHashmap(){

    HashMap<String, List<Date>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<Date>>();

    List<Date> dt = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Date d1 = new Date();
    Date d2 = new Date();
    Date d3 = new Date();
    dt.add(d1);
    dt.add(d2);
    dt.add(d3);
    hm.put("one", dt);
    hm.put("two", dt);
    hm.put("three",dt);

    return hm;

}
```

and the result is:

> two and value is: [Thu Jun 11 14:54:22 CEST 2015, Thu Jun 11 14:54:22
>   CEST 2015, Thu Jun 11 14:54:22 CEST 2015]
>
> one and value is: [Thu Jun 11 14:54:22 CEST 2015, Thu Jun 11 14:54:22
>   CEST 2015, Thu Jun 11 14:54:22 CEST 2015]
>
> three and value is: [Thu Jun 11 14:54:22 CEST 2015, Thu Jun 11
>   14:54:22 CEST 2015, Thu Jun 11 14:54:22 CEST 2015]

Where is the differenct in using a non Standard object as a key???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the answer as you changed the question.

If you want to use custom object as key in `HashMap`, you have to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` method in your custom object. [here](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java-collections-framework/sets-maps-user-objects-java-collections-framework-video-tutorial-part-6.html) is the example of how to do that .

---

Previous answer for checking size of list in jsp ( original question.)

Try using `${fn:length(myItem.value)}` to check list size. For this add `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>` in your jsp

EL works on getters and setter. If you are doing `list.size`, it looks for a method `list.getSize()` on `List` object, which is not there. It has `list.size()` instead. So we have to use this jstl function to retrieve size of list.

Comment: size is 0  - that's why i don't get a value. but java tells me, there is a value (see the for each in java above)

Comment: are you getting `0` printed in jsp ? I doubt that

Comment: yes, i do!  if there wouldn't be a 0, a i would have been able to get the value with my jsp code too

Comment: are you getting same output using the above solution which I gave ?

Comment: yes, as i wrote... i also added some more output to my original question

Comment: if i use: list.size i get nothing - with your fn: length(myitem.value) it get a 0 printed

Comment: As I explained, list.size is not valid, so you can skip that. now it seems to be some logic issue in your code. Also `<c:forEach var="myItem" items="${controller.giveMeTheHashMap().values()}" >
    ${myItem}
</c:forEach>` using this what output you are getting. I think you are printing list object directly here

Comment: i want the list values in my oiriginal posting!....
the problem is, that with my original explanation, the list seems to be empty - that's why i showed in a differnt way, that it its not!

Comment: hey @Amit.rk3 - I totally edited the question, to make it much more clearer...
the problem is not the value, the problem is the non standard object key

Answer (score 0):

as far as i recognized, the forEach is not working with a non java-standard object.
the best is to make a wrapper class

```
public class QualificationProductWithListOfOrderingMailingDate {

    private HashMap<QualifiedProduct,List<Date>> qualificationProductWithListOfOrderingMailingDate;

    public HashMap<QualifiedProduct,List<Date>> getQualificationProductWithListOfOrderingMailingDate() {
        return qualificationProductWithListOfOrderingMailingDate;
    }

    public void setQualificationProductWithListOfOrderingMailingDate(
            HashMap<QualifiedProduct,List<Date>> qualificationProductWithListOfOrderingMailingDate) {
        this.qualificationProductWithListOfOrderingMailingDate = qualificationProductWithListOfOrderingMailingDate;
    } 

}
```

than it is no problem at all to loop over every product:

```
<ui:repeat var="x" value="#{testController.createAndReturnHashmap()}">
    #{x.qualifiedProduct.abstractProductId},#{x.qualifiedProduct.abstractProductCode}

    <ui:repeat var="dt" value="#{x.dates}">
            #{dt}
    </ui:repeat>

</ui:repeat>
```