# Iterate over list of maps using nested ui:repeat

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am have a list of maps , each map contains number of values `List<Map<Integer, String>> recordsList` what I need to do is to iterate over the list and iterate also over each value in each map to form a table, this is my code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <ui:repeat id="record-table" var="c" value="#{Bean.recordsList}">
        <tr>
          <ui:repeat var="m" value="#{c.values}">
            <td>#{m}</td>
          </ui:repeat>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

My problem is this is not working, how to make it work?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ui:repeat don't support iteration over maps.
Follow the link for more details:
[ui:repeat doesn't work with Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552804/uirepeat-doesnt-work-with-map)

Comment: ok , does h:dataTable do ?? , I have to view an excel sheet dynamically,without knowing the number or columns

Comment: It won't support either. You need to wrap a List over map to do so

Comment: If I changed the map to list , so it would be `List<List<String>> myList` would it work??

Comment: ui:repeat or h:datatable always work with List items.  Probably try with List<Entry<K,V>>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly using a Map with ui:repeat.

You could output the key and value like this however:

```
<ui:repeat var="key" value="#{c.values.keySet().toArray()}">
    <td>key:#{key}</td>
    <td>value:#{c.values.get(key)}</td>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't do either