# Build 'key' for resource bundle on the fly?

Tags: java, jsf

can I 'build' my resource bundle key within a jsf servlet?

Something like this:

```
<cc:myComponent type="person" />
<cc:myComponent type="payment" />
```

myComponent:

```
<composite:attribute name="type" />

<h:outputText value="message.xx.type" />
```

bundle:

```
message.xx.person = i'm a person
message.xx.payment = i'm a payment
```

Possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EL 2.2 it can be done using following code at component's implementation section:

```
<h:outputText value="#{'message.xx.'.concat(cc.attrs.type)]}" />
```

The issue is regarding concatenating strings in EL and there is another question about it:
[Concatenate strings in JSF/JSP EL and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192759/concatenate-strings-in-jsf-jsp-el-and-javascript)

If you are not using EL 2.2 then you will find the answer at the same question I've just linked here.

Comment: Yes I might be using EL 2.2, or rather just added it to maven. Though cannot get it to work?

Comment: Ok sorry, I missed the dot after xx. So it really works, very nice. tyvm! Only left: eclipse is complaining about not resolving the bundle key. Can I somehow teach eclipse to being able to handle these kind of expressions?

Comment: can't help you with that, I use IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE, I think you will need to ask another question for that...