# jsf - el escape dot

Tags: jsf, escaping, el

I have following audio tag in my markup:

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" hidden="true">
    <source src="#{resource['sounds:filename.mp3']}" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="#{resource['sounds:filename.ogg']}" type="audio/ogg" />
    <embed src="#{resource['sounds:filename.mp3']}" hidden="true"/>
</audio>
```

I want to wrap this inside a custom composite component which gets the filename as an attribute.

```
<source src="#{resource['sounds:cc.attrs.filename.mp3']}" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

This is obvious not working since .mp3 now seems to be a child of filename. 
How do I escape the dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameterize it using `<ui:param>`.

```
<ui:param name="resourceIdentifier" value="sounds:#{cc.attrs.filename}.mp3" />
<source src="#{resource[resourceIdentifier]}" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

Comment: Thanks and pretty obvious now, but no way you get this idea by your own. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to use is a concatenation function for Facelets.

Either [create one as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192759/concatenate-strings-in-jsf-jsp-el-and-javascript), or set up [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) in your project, so you can use its nice [String manipulation functions](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings), like this:

```
<source src="#{resource[of:concat('sounds:', cc.attrs.filename)]}"
    type="audio/mpeg" />
```