# Getting results for questionnaire JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, dictionary

I have just one idea as realize getting user's answers. I decide use `List<String> questionsWithAnswers` and put in this list pairs like '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '2_1'. Something like this. But even with this idea I have a problem. And also important I'll use web-service (it's a constraint for using map for example as structure for saving pairs question and answer).

********   My bean ********

```
    public class TestBean implements Serializable{
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private List<Test> testList;
        private List<Answer> answerList;
        private List<Subject> subjectList;
        private Map<Question, List<QuestionAnswer>> mapQestionsWithAnswers;
        private List<String> questionAnswerList;
        
        private Long subjectId = 0L;
        private Test test;
//...
}
```

**getTest.xhtml**

```
<c:forEach items="#{test.testBean.mapQestionsWithAnswers}"
                    var="entry">
                    <h:inputHidden value="#{entry.key.questionId}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.key.question}" rendered="#{not empty entry.value}"/>                   
                    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{test.testBean.questionAnswerList}" layout="pageDirection">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{entry.value}" var="ans"
                            itemValue="#{fnc:concat(ans.answer.answerId, entry.key.questionId)}"
                            itemLabel="${ans.answer.answer}" />                         
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                </c:forEach>
                <h:commandButton value="#{msgs['page.content.passtest']}" action="#{test.passTest}" />
```

For concatination questionId with answerId I use concat. I find this in [Concatenate strings in JSF/JSP EL and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192759/concatenate-strings-in-jsf-jsp-el-and-javascript)

But I cant get value **`entry.key.questionId`** inside **`itemValue="#{fnc:concat(ans.answer.answerId, entry.key.questionId)}"`**

I don't understand why.

Where can I make a mistake? And I want to ask some source on more logic and simple decision similar problem. Thanks

Comment: why areyou using JSTL in a jsf 2 project? Much better to use the jsf `<ui:repeat>` tag

Comment: @SteveAtkinson because I read about problems with output Map in jsf

Comment: where? I've never had problems using maps or lists with ui:repeat. The problem with JSTL tags is that they execute in the wrong part of the lifecycle and cause unexpected results. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: @SteveAtkinson Ok, I try rewrite with <ui:repeat>. What do you think about my idea with List<String>? May be that's will be the best solution my problem that's why I'm going to use web services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to concatenate :

```
itemValue="#{fnc:concat(ans.answer.answerId, entry.key.questionId)}"
```

could be as simple as :

```
itemValue="#{ans.answer.answerId}, #{entry.key.questionId}"
```

Comment: What do you think about idea with `List<String>` and `JSTL` istead of `ui:repeat`?

Comment: I agree that ui:repear and c:forEach are not executed in the same lifecycle so that it can cause problem.

Comment: Do you prefer jstl or jsf tags in case map?

Comment: It depend of every project, in your case I think ui:repeat will work better.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using your own method to concatenate? You can use a bean named `concatenatorBean` having method

`String customConcat(String str1, String str2) {

   return str1+"_"+str2;


}`

Then in `getTest.xhtml` you can use your own concatenator to solve the problem.

Comment: My problem that's I get empty questionAnswerList

Comment: How you are initializing questionAnswerList? you can initialize it when creating TestBean (in the constructor of TestBean).

Comment: I initialize list in constructor TestBean. problem that this list is empty, not null.

Comment: If you don't have getter setter of questionAnswerList please add them and try again.

Comment: can you give me the actual stack trace of the Exception?

Comment: I think the problem is anywhere else. can you post in more details?