# Use dynamic element ID in #{rich:clientId()} function

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, el

We can get element by static ID using `rich:clientId()` function as follows

```
document.getElementById('#{rich:clientId(JSF_ID)}').click();
```

However, I need to use a dynamic ID which takes the form of `var + "_ID"` where `var` can be `employee`, `student`, etc and thus resulting in `employee_ID`, `student_ID` as actual ID.

I tried as follows:

```
dynamicID = var + '_ID';
document.getElementById('#{rich:clientId(dynamicID)}').click();
```

However, it didn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: rich:clientId is evaluated by server. if you check the generated js code, you will see that.

Comment: Please specify the requirement you're trying to achieve the wrong way. As stated in MrD's answer and in johny's comment, there is no way to run JSF-related artifacts in the client side. So, you either have to establish a way of finding the components without resorting to the server-side finders, or attach all proper finders on the server so that all of the JavaSscipt functions are already dealing with proper component ids.

Comment: @BalusC you assume that dynamicID = 'anyText' + '_ID'; 
any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting `dynamicID` via JavaScript, am I right?
If yes, the EL-expression `#{rich:clientId(dynamicID)}` cannot be evaluated as EL on the server during the rendering of the page since the `dynamicID` is only available on the client (=browser) when the page has already been built up on the server and sent to the browser.

Where does `var` come from? How is it applied to the component with the `dynamicID`? Can't you use the same approach for the `getElementById`?

Comment: assume that dynamicID = 'anyText' + '_ID';

Answer (score 0):

For concatenating a variable with a constant in JSF on server-side, see the following already answered post [Concatenate strings in JSF/JSP EL and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2192897/1269441). Basically it gives you a how-to in creation of an own concatenation function for jsp/jsf. Works pretty need.

As a hint: you can use `#{rich:element(JSF_ID)}` instead of `document.getElementById('#{rich:clientId(JSF_ID)}')` to keep the source readeable - it will render identical results.

Good luck...