# How can I give dynamic id to selectBooleanCheckbox in primefaces datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to set dynamic id to many check box in `<p:dataTable>`.
how can i give it please help.

```
<p:column id="sipyes">  
      <center>
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  rendered="#{var1[5]}" id="#{var1[4]}">
      <p:ajax listener="#{pmmbean.checkitem(var1[2],var1[0],var1[3])}"/>
      </h:selectBooleanCheckbox><br/>
      <h:outputText value="#{var1[4]}" rendered="#{var1[5]}"/>
      </center>
</p:column>
```

Here I can get value of `var1[4]` but it can not set in the id attribute.

Here I got id selectBooleanCheckbox id is empty.

and got this type of error.

How can I resolve it?

Got this type of Error :

> HTTP Status 500 - Empty id attribute is not allowed.

Comment: The HTML `<center>` tag was deprecated a long ago. Make use of CSS instead.

Comment: Do you want to have checkboxes like [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf) for row selection? You can use `<p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>` as shown on the showcase. Checkboxes will be available for multiple row selection.

Comment: No Tiny i have many checkboxes in all column and particular checkbox in the cell redered from the database. so i want to give id particular that checkbox.

Comment: Are you sure `var1` is initialized correctly in the corresponding managed bean? It is difficult to tell without looking into the corresponding JSF managed bean.

Comment: Here var1 is not define in the JSF managed bean. var1 is the <p:datatable> variable.

Answer (score 1):

By default all elements inside a `dataTable` take dynamic IDs, for example:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:dataTable id="myTable" value="..." var="...">
        <p:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="firstCheckbox" value="..." />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="secondCheckbox" value="..." />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Your checkboxes IDs will be:

- For the first row `myForm:myTable:0:firstCheckbox` and `myForm:myTable:0:secondCheckbox`
- For the second row `myForm:myTable:1:firstCheckbox` and `myForm:myTable:1:secondCheckbox`

and so on.

Unless you want your custom id format, you can always create your own facelets taglib functions.
Based on [this tutorial](http://qussay.com/2013/06/08/parametrized-messages-in-jsf-with-facelets-taglib-functions/) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192759/concatenate-strings-in-jsf-jsp-el-and-javascript/2192897#2192897) you can create your own id generator method, it would be something like this:

```
public static String generateId(String value, Integer index) {
    return value + "_" + index;
}
```

Then use it in your page:

```
xmlns:fnc="http://yournamespace.com/fnc"
...
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:dataTable id="myTable" value="..." var="item" rowIndexVar="index">
        <p:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="#{fnc:generateId(item.name, index)}" value="..." />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Just make sure you avoid duplicate IDs, by setting a unique value for each one, like I've used the loop index in my example.

Comment: Got error: @143,102 id="#{var1[4]+'_'+rowIndex}" For input string: "_"

Comment: @R'Skot I've updated my answer, hopefully it will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've just put an random name before the dynamic id!
Like this :

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox  rendered="#{var1[5]}" id="random#{var1[4]}">
```

And then set something that you might use like :

```
$('#random#{var1[4]}').something();
```

Hope this works for you!